# Terminate and Suspend activity in Windows workflow Foundation

Tags: workflow-foundation

I need to stop the execution Is there any procedures for using terminate and suspend activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends exactly what you want to do. There is a Terminate Activity will terminate the workflow instance that is running and has reached that activity. Once terminated, that workflow instance will be dead and will never be restartable.

Suspend is something you can call on a WorkflowInstance e.g.

```
WorkflowInstance instance = runtime.GetWorkflow(instanceId);
instance.Suspend("Paused for some good reason");

// do something here

instance.Resume();
```

Comment: it gives me this error please help "This operation can only be performed with a started WorkflowRuntime."

Answer (score 2):

This sample at the microsoft website should help you with the suspend and terminate Activity

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742189.aspx