# How to terminate worflow instance?

Tags: workflow-foundation, appfabric

I have a non persisted workflow instance, which is shown as "In progress" in AppFabric dashboard. How can I terminate / cancel it?

I am wondering why this instance is not cancelled even after "iisreset" as it is a not persisted workflow instance...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Terminate and Suspend activity in Windows workflow Foundation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327486/terminate-and-suspend-activity-in-windows-workflow-foundation)

Answer (score 1):

According to [Terminate and Suspend activity in Windows workflow Foundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327486/terminate-and-suspend-activity-in-windows-workflow-foundation)

```
WorkflowInstance instance = runtime.GetWorkflow(instanceId);
instance.Suspend("Paused for some good reason");

// do something here

instance.Resume();
```

Also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742189.aspx

Comment: Instead of replying, you can flag as duplicate.